# How to fix windows phone page navigation failed?

Tags: c#

I have a MainPage.xaml from which I wish to navigate to a Timetable.xaml page but I get a NavigationFailed pointing me to:

```
 // Code to execute if a navigation fails
        private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
        }
```

My code for the navigation is:

```
 private void imgTimeTable_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Timetable.xaml/", UriKind.Relative));
            MessageBox.Show("Images");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the slash at the end of your Uri

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Timetable.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```